# string could not be set to a Guid value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, guid

I am using Entity Framwork Code First and i have a table Session (Id primary key long not null, SessionId UniqueIdentify not null) and my entity Session:

```
    public class Session
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public string SessionId { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
        }
```

when i Create the session it is ok get no exception but when i get Session By Status I getting an Error "The 'SessionId' property on 'Session' could not be set to a 'System.Guid' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'"

My GetSessionByStatus Method :

```
public QueryResult<Session> GetSessionByStatus(DbConnection connection, string status, int size = 0, int index = 0)
        {
            QueryResult<Session> result = new QueryResult<Session>();
            try
            {
                using (var uow = new StagingUnitOfWork(connection))
                {
                    result.Data = uow.SessionRepository
                    .FindAll(s => (s.Status == status)).Skip(size * index).Take(size).ToList();

                    if (result.Data != null && result.Data.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        result.QuerySuccess = true;
                        result.Message = "Query Session Data Successful";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.QuerySuccess = false;
                        result.Message = "Session have no result";
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Data = null;
                result.QuerySuccess = false;
                result.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

The Resule.Data throw that exception.
Please help me fix this Exception Thank for advance

Comment: We don't know what `StagingUnitOfWork` so it's hard to help. You really need to provide a [mcve] to get help for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for your database value, stored as a Guid, to be placed into a String. You can probably set SessionID in your object as Guid instead of string to fix this.